# Circular rotating views

Tags: ios7

I'm fairly new to iOS programming and am trying to build an app that contains several pages of buttons. I would like to be able to navigate between each page in a circular fashion. A left swipe goes to previous page, right swipe goes to next page. When I get to the last page it should go to first and vise-versa.

Navigation controllers only seem to support stack based push/pop functionality which doesn't suit the sort of design I'm looking for. Can anyone recommend a design that works best for the type of behavior I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a UIPageViewController! I have a "flashcard" app that works exactly as you describe, using a UIPageViewController.